# Tortoise SVN importing into repository but not updating the folder icon

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Tortoise SVN to connect to java.net repositories.
I used Tortoise SVN 1.7 to import a project (a folder) into the `{base_repository_url}/projectFolderName` repository.

It imported all the content into the folder onto the folder on the repository, but in my local machine, still I don't see any special SVN icon on my folder because the .svn folder ain't created inside my project folder.

Secondly, I browsed the repository but the project folder has been successfully imported. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in Tortoise SVN 1.7 which even after importing the folder don't create the .svn folder inside it and hence again right-clicking on the same project folder gives you the option to Import Again, which you cannot do definitely since the project has already been imported and re-trying gives you an error.

Comment: Read [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Icon overlays will appear (if enabled) only on **Working Copy** objects
- When your import some unversioned tree, you add it to **Repository**
- Importing tree doesn't convert tree into versioned Working Copy
- In order to work with data in Repository, you have to checkout from Repository into another, previously empty, directory, which become Working Copy (with overlays) after it

Comment: Thanks, I got it.
I first imported the project and then check-out the same project onto the same folder and now it became the Working Copy (with overlays)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, importing a directory doesn't make your local directory become a working copy.  You need to checkout again.  So it is by-design not working as what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

From [Importing Data Into A Repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html) chapter:

> The folder imported does not become a working copy. You have to do a
>   checkout to copy the files back from the server.

That is why you don't see **.svn** folders. Is that right or wrong depends on what are you going to do with the project files. To contribute for the project you need to use **Checkout** menu command. See [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-wc)